# How to save and query dynamic fields in Spring Data MongoDB?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

I'm on Spring boot 1.4.x branch and Spring Data MongoDB.

I want to extend a Pojo from `HashMap` to give it the possibility to save new properties dynamically.

I know I can create a `Map<String, Object>` properties in the Entry class to save inside it my dynamics values but I don't want to have an inner structure. My goal is to have all fields at the root's entry class to serialize it like that:

```
{
   "id":"12334234234",
   "dynamicField1": "dynamicValue1",
   "dynamicField2": "dynamicValue2"
}
```

So I created this Entry class:

```
@Document
public class Entry extends HashMap<String, Object> {

    @Id
    private String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

And the repository like this:

```
public interface EntryRepository extends MongoRepository<Entry, String> {
}
```

When I launch my app I have this error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'entryRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: Could not lookup mapping metadata for domain class java.util.HashMap!
```

Any idea?

Comment: Franck - having answered your question, please acknowledge by marking the answer as correct if it helped your understanding :)

Comment: Have you tried extending BasicDBObject ? Something like `public class Entry extends BasicDBObject `

Comment: Yep same error.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### TL; DR;

1. Do not use Java collection/map types as a base class for your entities.
2. Repositories are not the right tool for your requirement.
3. Use `DBObject` with `MongoTemplate` if you need dynamic top-level properties.

### Explanation

Spring Data Repositories are [repositories in the DDD sense](http://static.olivergierke.de/lectures/ddd-and-spring/#ddd.building-blocks.repositories) acting as persistence gateway for your well-defined aggregates. They inspect domain classes to derive the appropriate queries. Spring Data excludes collection and map types from entity analysis, and that's why extending your entity from a `Map` fails.

Repository query methods for dynamic properties are possible, but it's not the primary use case. You would have to use [SpEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions) queries to express your query:

```
public interface EntryRepository extends MongoRepository<Entry, String> {

    @Query("{ ?0 : ?1 }")
    Entry findByDynamicField(String field, Object value);
}
```

This method does not give you any type safety regarding the predicate value and only an ugly alias for a proper, individual query.

Rather use `DBObject` with `MongoTemplate` and its query methods directly:

```
List<DBObject> result = template.find(new Query(Criteria.where("your_dynamic_field")
                                          .is(theQueryValue)), DBObject.class);
```

`DBObject` is a `Map` that gives you full access to properties without enforcing a pre-defined structure. You can create, read, update and delete `DBObject`s objects via the Template API.

### A last thing

You can declare dynamic properties on a nested level using a `Map`, if your aggregate root declares some static properties:

```
@Document
public class Data {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private Map<String, Object> details;
}
```

Comment: It's a nice explanation so I upvote. Finally, I have made a Map in my POJO and serializer/deserializer in jackson to put details content at the root level.

Answer (score 3):

Here we can achieve using JSONObject

The entity will be like this

```
@Document
public class Data {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private JSONObject details;
    //getters and setters
}
```

The POJO will be like this

```
public class DataDTO {
    private String id;
    private JSONObject details;
        //getters and setters
}
```

In service

```
Data formData = new Data();
JSONObject details = dataDTO.getDetails();
details.put("dynamicField1", "dynamicValue1");
details.put("dynamicField2", "dynamicValue2");
formData.setDetails(details);
mongoTemplate.save(formData );
```

i have done as per my business,refer this code and do it yours. Is this helpful?

Comment: If I do that, is it always possible to query fields ?$

Comment: yeah,you don't have the inner structure also(if you use above code format). So easily you can query the fields.

Comment: @jai - How to retrieve the values back and map it to a pojo?